# Will Bitlocker drive encryption restart if my laptop runs out of power?

Tags: encryption, bitlocker

I am currently in the process of encrypting my C: drive, but will need to travel in the next couple of hours. I have set the laptop to stay awake, even with a closed screen to keep the encryption running as long as possible, but I am worried that when it runs out of power the drive will only be part encrypted. Does anyone know if the process will continue where it left off, or if I'll need to start the process again?

Any help greatly appreciated.

If no one answers, I'll update any readers on what happens once I know.

Comment: For the sake of future readers, I'll note that more than once I've done a hard reboot when BitLocker's encryption process has been frozen for hours and the program has stopped responding (and therefore encryption can't be paused), and upon reboot, BitLocker has resumed encrypting. The hard reboot was because the computer wouldn't complete the shutdown process (and didn't provide the normal "programs still running" warnings). There may be a better way to deal with BitLocker not responding, but that's been my experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitlocker encryption can be interrupted when the power is off, it will resume from where it left off; the next time you boot up the machine.